# In React hooks, how do I refer to a generic attribute of an object in my state I want to change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm using React hooks for my React 16.13.0 application.  I'm trying to write a generic function to update an attribute of a complex object in my state.

```
  const [coop, setCoop] = React.useState(props.coop);
```

My form contains elements like below

```
<Input
        inputType={"text"}
        title={"Name"}
        name={"name"}
        value={coop.name}
        placeholder={"Enter cooperative name"}
        handleChange={handleInput}
        errors={errors}
      />
...
<Input
        inputType={"text"}
        title={"Street"}
        name={"coop.addresses[0].formatted"}
        value={coop.addresses[0].formatted}
        placeholder={"Enter address street"}
        handleChange={handleInput}
        errors={errors}
      />
```

I've tried to write the following functions, but I don't know how to refer to a generic attribute of my "coop" state in my function.

```
  const handleInput = (e) => {
    let self = this;
    let value = e.target.value;
    let name = e.target.name;
    if (name.indexOf("[") === -1) {
      console.log("updating " + name + " with value:" + value);
      setValue(coop, name, value);
    } else {
      const keys = name.split(/[\[\].]+/);
      setCoop(updateValue(coop, keys, value));
    }
  };

  const updateValue = (obj, name, value, index = 0) => {
    if (name.length - 1 > index) {
      const isArray = Array.isArray(obj[name[index]]);
      obj[name[index]] = this.updateValue(
        isArray ? [...obj[name[index]]] : { ...obj[name[index]] },
        name,
        value,
        index + 1
      );
    } else {
      obj = { ...obj, [name[index]]: value };
    }
    return obj;
  };
    ...

  const setValue = (obj, is, value) => {
    console.log("setting " + is + " of value: " + value);
    if (typeof is == "string") return setValue(obj, is.split("."), value);
    else if (is.length === 1 && value !== undefined) {
      return setCoop({ coop: obj[is[0]] = value });
    } else if (is.length === 0) return obj;
    else return setValue(obj[is[0]], is.slice(1), value);
  };
```

Having trouble with this line

```
setCoop({ coop: obj[is[0]] = value });
```

How do I refer to a generic attribute of "coop" and its value?

Comment: You should take a look at [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer), very easy to use and solves this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not related to hooks or React, its JavaScript.

Basically you asking how to set a generic key in an object.

You should use utility function for this as its not trivial solution, see [`lodash.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/#set)

> Sets the value at path of object. If a portion of path doesn't exist, it's created. Arrays are created for missing index properties while objects are created for all other missing properties. Use _.setWith to customize path creation.

```
const object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
 
_.set(object, 'a[0].b.c', 4);
console.log(object.a[0].b.c);
// => 4
 
_.set(object, ['x', '0', 'y', 'z'], 5);
console.log(object.x[0].y.z);
// => 5
```

For your specific case, supposing `obj[is[0]]` is the path you can set the state with it.

But be sure to not mutate state, [treat it as immutable](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) i.e use `_.set` on copy of state.

Comment: I have been told in React, you should always use the "setObj" method instead of manipulating the object itself.  Here you are using lodash to manipulate the object itself, unless i'm misunderstanding your answer.  Am I correct that it is ok to manipulate the object itself without using the "setObj" that it seems is standard in React?

Comment: You are right, don't mutate the state in React, you can make a copy of the state and then use the `_.set`